# I have a DIV and there are four little pictures in

Tags: css

I have a DIV named mediashelter and there are four small photos inside the DIV

```
#mediashelter
{

    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:black;

}
```

and inside the div are four small pictures placed vertically using

```
<div id="mediashelter" >

<a href="http://www.facebook.com" id="fbid" class="socialmedia" target="_blank"><img src="./images/fubu.jpg"></a><br>
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com" id="liid" class="socialmedia" target="_blank"><img src="./images/li.jpg"></a><br>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com" id="twitterid" class="socialmedia" target="_blank"><img src="./images/t.jpg"></a><br>
<a href="https://plus.google.com" id="googleplusid" class="socialmedia" target="_blank"><img src="./images/g.jpg"></a>


</div>
```

how do I center the four small pictures inside the black rectangle named mediashelter?  Thanks a lot once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `text-align: center` to `#mediashelter`, it works perfectly.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/3Ff63/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="mediashelter" align="center">
```